# Google Material Design Lite: Single Page Header

Tags: html, responsive-design, material-design

Trying to build out a responsive single page for my Slack app but I can't seem to get the header to be responsive, it just disappears on smaller screens. I was thinking I might need to use the `mdl-grid` class, but not sure if that is the best practice. Here is what I have written:

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Slack Riddles</span>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored">
      Add to Slack
    </button>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, this is a silly question. Maybe it will help someone else. Include the `mdl-layout--fixed-header` class.

`<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">`